# How do I keep track of multiple broadcast receivers

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 different files that need to initiale the same broadcast receiver. I am having problems with retrieving the results.  Somehow I'm getting null values on occasion which is a result of not being able to properly reference the class that initiated the scan.

Here is a code example.

```
public void Connection_Logic (Context c)

    IntentFilter wififilter; 
    wififilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION); 
    public WifiManager wifiManager;
    wifireceiver = serviceConsume.wifireceiver;
    c.registerReceiver(wifireceiver, wififilter);
    wifiManager.startScan();
}

public class serviceConsume {
    public WifiManager wifiMan;
    wifiMan = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    public BroadcastReceiver wifireceiver = new Wifi_Broadcast(this);
    IntentFilter wififilter; 
    wififilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION); 
    registerReceiver(wifireceiver, wififilter);
    wifiMan.startScan();
}

public class Wifi_Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ServiceConsume main;
    public Connection_Logic ConnLog;

    public Wifi_Broadcast(ServiceConsume main) {
        super();
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Wifi_Broadcast(Connection_Logic ConnLog) {
        super();
        this.ConnLog = ConnLog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        if(main != null) {
            List<ScanResults> results = ConnLog.wifiManager.getScanResults();
        } else if (ConnLog != null) {
            List<ScanResults> results = ConnLog.wifiMan.getScanResults();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas, why I might be getting null values for results? Am I doing this wrong? If anyone has a code example of this working, it'd be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(main != null) {
            List<ScanResults> results = ConnLog.wifiManager.getScanResults();
        } else if (ConnLog != null) {
            List<ScanResults> results = main.wifiMan.getScanResults();
        }
```

in your `else if` you use main, but main is null.. Maybe it need to look like this:

```
   if(main != null) {
                List<ScanResults> results = main.wifiMan.getScanResults();   
            } else if (ConnLog != null) {
                List<ScanResults> results = ConnLog.wifiManager.getScanResults();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Finn, That was actually a typo. But I figured out my problem, which involved polling receiver too quickly. If you poll too quickly, there will be null values because the receiver is no longer registered.  I appreciate the help, and I'm glad to know there was no problem with my logic. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave - so how did you stop polling quickly?